# Different links with target = _blank works only twice

Tags: javascript

I have a code that covers the whole content with a link (target= _blank), then turns that link's display into none, brings another link and so on.

In my browser everything works just fine but I got a complaint about how only 2 of these links work.

No matter which link they click, after the second one it doesn't work.

Did the same thing with addEventListener and onclick but they caused different problems so therefore I used "a href".

I only can use JavaScript to create these elements and unable to use plain HTML.

I searched about browser's behaviors on multiple new tab or window but couldn't find anything useful.

**This is how I create the links:**

```
var hidden= document.createElement("a");
hidden.href="somelink";
hidden.style.height="100%";
hidden.style.width="100%";
hidden.target="_blank";
hidden.style.display="none";
container.appendChild(hidden);
```

**And to make them appear, I add an event listener to a video and make them appear and disappear the right time.**

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate",function () {
  if(video.currentTime>=3 && video.currentTime<5){
    hidden.style.display="block";
  } else if(video.currentTime>=5 && video.currentTime<6) {
    hidden.style.display="none";
  } 
}
```

Is it a browser behavior that blocks the multiple new tabs or should I look for the answer in something else in my code?

Comment: Please show the complete code that is relevant to this issue as a snippet (use the `<>` button when editing the question to insert one) so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: @CharlieStanard No, it's not. As you'll see from that article, the OP is using `window.open()` which is JavaScript code for opening a window. This is an HTML element that a user clicks on. Browsers block auto-generated windows, not ones that users perform an action to open and in this case, we're talking about regular hyperlinks, which would not be blocked.

Comment: There isn't any other things that I think is relevant but the whole code is actually is just a message that is sending to the top of the page then executed there. Basically I listen the video time and show the links when the time comes then turn their display into none as you can see there

Comment: Please add the HTML for the `video` element and where in the overall code you've placed the code that creates the hyperlinks. In short, post your code the way that you actually have it and if you do this in a snippet, we can run it and see exactly what's happening.